# What permission level do you need to get data from Project Server REST APIs?

Tags: permissions, rest, project-server

I'm working on a web part that sits on a SharePoint site in a Project Web App instance, and reads project data using the Project Server REST APIs.

We recently got a few schedulers involved to be beta testers.  I added them to the Project Managers group at the root of their PWA instance, and the SharePoint site is a subsite that inherits permissions.

I had them connect their MS Project client apps to the server, and upload a project file they had to the server.  They were able to connect to the server that way and upload and publish their project file without issue.  (And by "upload", I mean they opened their local project file, chose "save as", and chose the server as the save as destination.)

However, when they went to their SharePoint site where the web part is, they were unable to load their project data. They *were* able to load the project data in the web part after I added them to the Administrators group, which makes it seem like it's being security trimmed?

So, if they were able to upload and publish a project file through the Project client app, and they are ostensibly the owners of that file because they uploaded it, why can't they access that file through the REST APIs with Project Manager permissions?  Do we need to somehow explicitly set permissions on the .mpp file in the server?  Obviously I don't want to have to elevate everyone to Administrator just so they can use the web part.